# How to solve Subscripts out of range error in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me to solve the error?
The error comes when executing line 7. The excel file that I opened has the worksheet name "Fault Code Report".

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Load_FSR()
Dim myFSR As String, FaultCode As Worksheet, ComplaintLog As Worksheet
Dim SerialNumber As String, 
    ComplaintNumber As String, 
    WarrantyStatus As String, 
    ComplaintDate As Date, 
    LongText As String,
    CustomerName As String

  myFSR = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for FSR")
  Workbooks.Open myFSR
  Set ComplaintLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUO Complaints Log")
  Set FaultCode = Workbooks(myFSR).Worksheets("Fault Code Report")
  Sheets(FaultCode).Select
  Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `myFSR` holds the full path of the workbook. However, when accessing the `Workbooks`-Collection, you need the name without path as index. Something like that:

```
dim wbName As string, p As Long
p = instrRev(myFSR, ".")
If p > 0 Then
    wbName = mid(myFSR, p+1)
Else
    wbName = myFSR
End If
Set FaultCode = Workbooks(wbName).Worksheets("Fault Code Report")
```

However, `Workbooks.Open` is a function that returns a reference to the opened worksheet, so it's much better to use that:

```
Dim fsrWB as Workbook
Set fsrWB = Workbooks.Open(myFSR)
Set FaultCode = fsrWB.Worksheets("Fault Code Report")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have opened that particular workbook, and still you refer to it via `Workbooks(myFSR)`, why don't you use `thisWorkbook`:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fault Code Report")
```

Comment: Are you mixing up `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Because I opened two workbooks, not sure whether the system know which workbook i mentioned to

Comment: Now I'm not sure anymore? Is my answer correct or should I replace `ThisWorkbook` by `ActiveWorkbook`? In any case, @ztee: in case my answer is useful, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the workbook create a reference to it and use that in the rest of the code.

```vb
Sub Load_FSR()
Dim wbFSR As Workbook
Dim myFSR As String, FaultCode As Worksheet, ComplaintLog As Worksheet
Dim SerialNumber As String
Dim ComplaintNumber As String
Dim WarrantyStatus As String
Dim ComplaintDate As Date
Dim LongText As String
Dim CustomerName As String

    myFSR = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for FSR")
    Set wbFSR = Workbooks.Open(myFSR)

    Set ComplaintLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RUO Complaints Log")
    Set FaultCode = wbFSR.Worksheets("Fault Code Report")
    Sheets(FaultCode).Select
    Range("B3").Select

End Sub
```